# Does Windows task scheduler cache dlls

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, .net, task-scheduler

I recently changed an existing scheduled task on a Windows 2008 r2 server by making it point to a new executable located in a different folder than the previous one. A few DLLs alongside the exe (a .NET console app) have changed as well.

The problem is, when executing the task it seems to have the same behavior as the old version. I double checked the location and moved the old folder away but the problem is still there.

The main behavior that has observably stayed the same while it should have changed is defined in one of the dlls. Is it possible that some DLLs that the exe relies upon have been cached by the system so that their old versions are still in use? If so, how to force them to be refreshed?

Note : the assemblies are not strongly signed but the new ones have a different version number.